# Google Apps start page - or embed login?

Tags: gmail, google-apps

We're using Google Apps where I work and we're trying to create a new 'start page' because the default one for Google Apps is terrible. I'd like to be able to either embed a Google Mail login form into my website, or modify the current 'start page' structure.

As far as I'm aware there's something called SSO, but I really don't know what it is. Heck I don't even know what the API is so I don't know where to even start in using it.

I've found a script to embed Gmail into a webpage: http://pastebin.com/H5q1Lz0P
The only problem with the script is when you enter your details it redirects to Gmail's login page. Your email is there in the email/username box but your password needs to be entered again.

1. Is there a way around the Gmail problem?
2. Or can someone give me a little insight on SSO - if that's what I need to do what I want.

**edit**
I also read somewhere Ajax can be used? Can someone give me some resources to get started with that? I don't know the Google platform what so ever, other than it's interface.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the sign in page, this is expected behavior and there's no way around it without using SSO due to a change and a standardization made a few months ago by Google. More information about this can be found [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/4421331).

As mentioned in the above and in your question, SSO is a way to get around this. If you're using SSO, users will be redirected from the new standard sign in page to your SSO page as long as they're within your subnet mask or if you don't have one. For general information about SSO with Google Apps check [this](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60224) out.

There are a number of third party SSO providers so it's just a matter of finding one that works for you and fits your environment (e.g. syncing accounts/passwords from an LDAP).